# Group data.table by consecutive runs of two id variables, without using split()

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, rle

My `data.table` looks like the following (see bottom of post for copy/paste data). Both the `id` and `category` variables are grouping variables.

```
    id category
 1:  1     B100
 2:  1     B100
 3:  1     D300
 4:  1     D300
 5:  1     B100
 6:  2     B100
 7:  2     F500
 8:  2     F500
 9:  2     E600
10:  2     E600
11:  3     T400
12:  3     B100
13:  3     T400
14:  3     T400
```

Assume that the data is ordered correctly as given. Within each `id` group, I want to create a variable that indicates the group of each consecutive run of `category` (eg. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191479/group-data-by-consecutive-runs-of-a-variable)).

For example, because `"B100"` has two consecutive runs within `id == 1` (rows 1:2 and row 5), the new variable should take the value `1` on rows 1:2, and `2` on row 5, since row 5 was the 'second time' that `category == "B100"` occured inside `id == 1`.

For the entire `data.table`, my desired output is:

```
    id category group
 1:  1     B100     1 # The first run of 
 2:  1     B100     1 # B100 in id 1, length 2
 3:  1     D300     1
 4:  1     D300     1
 5:  1     B100     2 # second run of "B100" within id 1, length 1
 6:  2     B100     1
 7:  2     F500     1
 8:  2     F500     1
 9:  2     E600     1
10:  2     E600     1 # no repeated category runs in id 2, so all 1
11:  3     T400     1
12:  3     B100     1
13:  3     T400     2 # The second run of 
14:  3     T400     2 # "T400" within id 3, length 2
```

One way to approach is problem is to use `data.table::rleid()` twice (let data be `DT`):

```
library(data.table)

DT[, group := rleid(category), by = id]

DT <- split(DT, by = "id")

DT <- lapply(DT,
       \(x) x[, group := rleid(group), by = category])

DT <- rbindlist(DT)
```

**Question:** Is there a way to do this that avoids splitting up by `id` in the second step?

[Motivation for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523083/group-data-frame-by-the-consecutive-runs-of-an-id-variable-and-find-earliest-and/73523315#73523315)

##### Data copy/paste

As `data.frame`s for more general use.

```
DT <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,3)),
           category = c("B100","B100","D300","D300","B100",
                        "B100","F500","F500","E600","E600",
                        "T400","B100","T400","T400"))


Output <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,3)),
           category = c("B100","B100","D300","D300","B100",
                        "B100","F500","F500","E600","E600",
                        "T400","B100","T400","T400"),
           group = c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using two grouped operations, no splitting:

```
Output <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,3)),
           category = c("B100","B100","D300","D300","B100",
                        "B100","F500","F500","E600","E600",
                        "T400","B100","T400"),
           group = c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2))

setDT(Output)

Output[, temp := rleid(category), by = .(id)][, result := as.integer(factor(temp)), by = .(id, category)]
Output
#     id category group temp result
#  1:  1     B100     1    1      1
#  2:  1     B100     1    1      1
#  3:  1     D300     1    2      1
#  4:  1     D300     1    2      1
#  5:  1     B100     2    3      2
#  6:  2     B100     1    1      1
#  7:  2     F500     1    2      1
#  8:  2     F500     1    2      1
#  9:  2     E600     1    3      1
# 10:  2     E600     1    3      1
# 11:  3     T400     1    1      1
# 12:  3     B100     1    2      1
# 13:  3     T400     2    3      2
Output[, all(group == result)]
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Ah, factor is the way around it, great, thanks! Can you explain more about why `as.integer(factor())` is required, rather than just `factor()`?

Comment: Internally, factors are stored as integers for each level, and it's those integers you get when you convert a factor with `as.integer()`. So `as.integer(factor(c("a", "b", "b", "a")))` gives `1, 2, 2, 1`.  In this case we've got integers (the `temp` values) that (looking at the id=1 category=B100 group) might be something like 1, 1, 3, 1. And other cases might have more ordered non-consecutive values that we want to convert to ordered consecutive integers. That's what `as.integer(factor())` does. The integer levels of a factor are ordered consecutive integers starting at 1.